# Dot operator with string instead of member in Scala

Tags: scala, variables, object, case-class, dot-operator

I have a case class as:

```
case class abc (startDate:DateTime, endDate:DateTime)
```

In a different `object` that can access this `case class`, instead of accessing `abc.startDate or abc.endDate`,
I would like to have a string that tells me whether it is start or end Date. So,

```
val decideStartOrEnd:String = "startDate"
```

Now I would like to get `abc.startDate` using this string variable `decideStartOrEnd`.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use pattern matching in scala to obtain concrete object depends of string.

```
case class abc (startDate:LocalDate, endDate:LocalDate){

  def getTime(typeTime: String) : LocalDate = typeTime match {
    case "startDate" => startDate
    case "endDate" => endDate
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument")
  }

}
```

and use it like this for example

```
val decideStartOrEnd = "startDate"

val abe = abc(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now())

abe.getTime(decideStartOrEnd);
```

of course you can just type:

```
abe getTime "startDate"
```

Comment: You need a 'catchall' pattern for your string match: case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException